# BWWalkthrough + viewDidAppear

Tags: swift, bwwalkthrough

I am using BWWalkthrough and able to swipe through all the view controllers in my tutorial. I'd like each VC to have small animations as they slide into view. I am having a really hard time figuring out how to trigger a function as a VC enters...

I have made a class for each VC and tried using viewDidAppear like so...

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    print("SHOW ORGANIZE")

    OrganizeImg.animation = "pop"
    OrganizeImg.curve = "easeOut"
    OrganizeImg.force = 1.0
    OrganizeImg.delay = 1.0
    OrganizeImg.animate()
}
```

It seems the animations on all the VCs are running at the same time (which makes sense as all VCs load at the same time).... not when they slide into view. Any ideas on how to handle this are really appreciated.

Thanks